# Swift change cgpoint .center value

Tags: ios, swift, cgpoint

I am using a CGPoint value to set where a animation starts.

```
transition.startingPoint = startButton.center
```

If I do `print(startButton.center)` the output will be: `(292.0, 22.0)`

What I now want to do is to edit that values Y position so the animation starts a bit lower on the screen and I can pass the new value to the `transition.startingPoint = newVal`

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
var startingPoint = startButton.center
startingPoint.y += 20
transition.startingPoint = startingPoint
```

Or:

```
let buttonCenter = startButton.center
transition.startingPoint = CGPoint(x: buttonCenter.x, y: buttonCenter.y + 20)
```